# Get method type in Scala sbt REPL

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there in `SBT` a way to display the data type of a Scala method?

In `GHC` (Haskell) we can do:

```
:t something
```

Is there any similar command in `SBT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the method with `_`, you'll see the arguments and the return type of the resulting partially applied method:

```
scala> def helloWorld(i: Int): Option[Int] = { Some(i) }
helloWorld: (i: Int)Option[Int]

scala> helloWorld _
res0: Int => Option[Int] = <function1>
```

Comment: It is actually called *partially applied method*

Answer (score 1):

No, sbt is only a build tool. You can however use the same command `:t` in the scala REPL. You can also start the scala REPL from sbt with your current environment with the sbt command `console`. As alexwriteshere already said, you have to partially apply methods to get their type.

Some examples:

```
scala> def foo(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x+y
foo: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> :t foo _
(Int, Int) => Int

scala> :t 3
Int

scala> :t List(1,2,3)
List[Int]
```